# What are the implications of two drives being extended in gparted?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

[image: screenshot of gparted partition]

The above is the configuration of my partitioning system in gparted. Windows is on sda1. Ubuntu is on sda6. I want to use unetbootin to install another Linux on sda5.

My question is: Why are sda5 and sda6 both included under the "extended" rubric?

I probably did something I didn't understand when installing.

Is this a problem, or can I just clear out sda5 and install as usual?

Comment: if any of the below replies answers your question, please, consider accepting it.

Comment: I didn't get the system. I voted answers up, but I didn't see the possibility to "accept." I accepted an answer. I wish I could accept more than one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely okay that there is more than 1 partition in the extended section of hard drive. You should probably read something on disk partitioning to get the idea.

There are however things to consider. For example Windows can only install on a primary partition, but as you see Linux doesn't require that, so you should be okay.

Answer (score 1):

The MSDOS partition table only has 4 slots for partitions.  To overcome this limit, you can use one of them as an extended partition, which is then subdivided into one or more logical partitions, numbered starting at partition 5.  In other words, the whole point of an extended partition is to hold multiple partitions inside it.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a Ubuntu live cd. Had problems myself resizing partitions but with a live cd it worked.

Comment: Please add more detail, such as how to do it, otherwise this is more fit for a comment.

Comment: I guess the TS is not asking how to resize partitions.

Comment: Perfectly aware that he didn't ask how to resize. But I guess you g o around it pretty much the same way. Insert a live cd, try ubuntu instead of installing and then manage your partitions in gparted.